# has_many, new, and single table inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have three models (`Student`, `Document`, and `CV`). `Document` has single table inheritance. My question is how do I create a CV off of `@student`? I've tried `@student.documents.new(type: CV)` but this gives me:

**Error**

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `safe_constantize' for #<Class:0x007fd1819adad0>
```

I know that I can do `CV.new(owner: @student)` but this doesn't feel as elegant.

**Models**

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :documents,
    as: :owner
end

class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :documents,
    as: :owner
end

class CV < Document
end
```

Comment: Doesn't the CV has to be a String at creation time? And then call #becomes on the document object to set the correct Class.

Comment: try `@student.documents.new(type: "CV")`

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is:

```
@cv = @student.documents.build
@cv.type = "CV"
```

See [ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy#build](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html#method-i-build)

Comment: That won't build a `CV` object. That will build a `Document` object.

Comment: There is no direct relation between so `@student.cvs.build` will not work. Unless you create such a relation of course. So you have to first build the document and then set its type `@cv.type = "CV"`. I updated my answer with this :-)